# Using Cocoa delegate in a Carbon Objective c++ app

Tags: cocoa, macos, delegates, click, macos-carbon

I hope someone will be able to help me since this issue is killing my productivity..
One week on this even if I am quite new to Mac development.

I have a Carbon application in which I want to add a feature:
Get the path of a file I double clicked in the finder.

I have

- modified the project to allow Objective C calls.
- setup a delegate object and assigned it to NSApp
- implemented `- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)app openFile:(NSString *)filename`
  in the delegate.

the problem: the delegate method is NOT hit when double click a file in the finder.

I am sure I am missing something (memory/scope issue ? Event loop issue (using RunApplicationEventLoop for now)

If somebody has an hint I would be pleased to hear it.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Carbon application, NSApp will be nil. NSApp is defined during the NSApplicationMain function, which is called to start a Cocoa application. In a Carbon application, you need to use Carbon methods to determine when an application is being opened. Install an event handler and listen for the 'odoc' apple event.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
event handler was actually my first approach but it does not work when the app is not already lauched.
It workd perfectly when the application is already lauched.
I used the following line.
AEInstallEventHandler ( kCoreEventClass, 'odoc',
          AEEventHandlerUPP( HandleOpenDocuments), 0L, false );
Am i still missing something ?

Comment: Where are you installing the handler? Maybe it goes through before you catch it? Apple's launch services documentation says you should still get the event if the application wasn't opened before (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-TP9 a little less than halfway down).

Comment: I install the handler at the first line of the main function.
The problem is now solved. One of the SDK I was using poped a dialog box, in debug, before I call RunApplicationEventLoop. The problem does not happen in release (in which the dialog box does not appear). I assume that the mechanism used to display this dialog box actually "eats" the odoc event explaining why it does not work when the application is not lauched.
Thank you for your help.